# Wildfly 10 Undertow report a 513 response but looking at the threads I only see 3 active sessions

Tags: resteasy, wildfly-10, undertow

I have a Wildfly 10.1 deployment which uses undertow to receive a stream of JPEG images. The sending client is reporting a 513 response from the Wildfly server. However, when I do a thread dump of the Wildfly server I see only 3 active sessions that seem to be responding to requests (I verify this by looking at threads that are executing my REST code). There are a number of threads that appear to be undertow related but they are idle waiting for something to happen. The inbound requests are REST requests.

Any idea why undertow is sending a 513 response? How can I go about looking at how many sessions undertow believes it has? Any other suggestions on how to debug this issue?

Thanks, David

Comment: Since 513 is not a standard code could you let us know what it says?

Comment: Undertow code 513 means it has reached its connection limit. However, I only see 3 active sessions from a thread dump.

Answer (score 0):

Undertow contains a build in handler called Request Limiting Handler. It limits the maximum number of concurrent requests, blocks further requests and puts them in a queue. If the queue is full then requests will be rejected with code 513 ([default implementation](http://undertow.io/javadoc/1.3.x/io/undertow/server/handlers/RequestLimit.html))